# Why would capping one sprinkler zone cause my toilets to whistle?

Tags: plumbing, irrigation

Ever since they capped one of the sprinkler zones in an area that no longer needs watering, two of my toilets start whistling when the sprinklers are running and only stop when I flush them.  How can I get this corrected?

Comment: You've told us almost nothing about your plumbing arrangement or what it means when you say your toilets are "whistling". It'll be difficult to help. Please *edit your question* to offer details and clarity.

Comment: Wow I have toilets that only flush . Teaching them to whistle is a new one to me. My only guess is that the pressure has changed since it did not do this before. It is possible that this is a minor water hammer.[damper example](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Quiet-Pipes-Washing-Machine-Water-Hammer-Arrester-38600/100069256?cm_mmc=Shopping%7cTHD%7cG%7c0%7cG-VF-PLA-D26P-Plumbing%7c&gclid=CN716N6lxs4CFc5lfgoduaQO6g&gclsrc=aw.ds) something like this may stop it. This is a guess from the description you gave.

Comment: The two toilets are they on the second floor of your house (assuming you have a multi-level house)? I'm guessing that between low water pressure, too much volumn going to sprinkers, and lots of head pressure that you are getting a vacuum effect.

Comment: Thank you all for the information.  I guess it sounds odd to say the toilets are whistling--maybe I should have said they are complaining with a high pitched whine!  Will put the discontinued sprinkler zone back into action with hopes of a cure.

Answer (score 3):

Whistling toilets after plumbing alterations which occurs continuously except when flushed most likely indicates that debris was dislodged and is now affecting proper seal of the fill valves.

Turn off the water to each toilet, disassemble each fill valve, and give them a thorough flush by cracking the supply valve and letting water flow through, rinsing the washers and internal components. Heck, now is as good a time as any to go ahead and rebuild them by replacing all internal gaskets/washers.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  The noise is only continuous while sprinklers are running.  We have decided to turn the sprinkler zone that was shut off back on and see if that will alleviate the problem.  If it continues ater that, while the sprinklers are on, will plan on having the toilets serviced as you noted since it seems to be a valve issue.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but thought I’d share in case someone else has the same issue.  Our toilet started making a whistling noise when our back sprinklers were on (they are the larger spray arm type).  I can only assume they were affecting the water pressure just enough to cause it.  We discovered the noise was coming from the part I’m pointing to.  Hubby checked it over for damage etc but to the eye it looked ok, put it back together but same issue.  So we bought a new toilet fill valve from Lowe’s for $8 and replaced it.  Problem solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with guest bathroom toilet whistling when irrigation was turned on in backyard. Replaced toilet fill valve and problem solved!